# Automatic SFTP login on Windows client

Tags: sftp

Is there a solution that allows automatic SFTP user/password login?

I thought that was possible just by putting a `.netrc file` in `$HOME` but unfortunately it's not working on SFTP.

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 2):

SFTP is based on SSH, so you can use the standard SSH key files. See `ssh-keygen(1)` and `ssh_config(5)`.

If you're dependent on password authentication you could use another SFTP client like [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to which you can provide the password through a command line parameter or configuration file.

Comment: in this case i have to use user/password instead of key authentication

Comment: You could use `lftp` or `curl`, see edit. But IMHO the correct solution[tm] would be using SSH keys.